# Pygame - blit is causing lag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am making a simple platformer game, when I add a background using `pygame.surface.blit()` it causes a lot of lag, However when I use `pygame.suface.fill()` it runs at ~120 fps.

How do I fix this?

```
# map vars
mapFloor = []
ground = 700
mapController(True)
bg1Colour = bg1Colour = transform.scale(image.load('assets/PNG/Backgrounds/set1_background.png'), (1280, 1024))
bg1Colour = [bg1Colour, bg1Colour.get_rect()]
bg1Tiles = transform.scale(image.load('assets/PNG/Backgrounds/set1_tiles.png'), (1280, 1024))
bg1Tiles = [bg1Tiles, bg1Tiles.get_rect()]
bg1Hills = transform.scale(image.load('assets/PNG/Backgrounds/set1_hills.png'), (1280, 1024))
bg1Hills = [bg1Hills, bg1Hills.get_rect()]            
           


while not finished:

    for events in event.get():
        exiCheck()
        playerController(True)

    surface.blit(bg1Colour[0], bg1Colour[1])
    surface.blit(bg1Tiles[0], bg1Tiles[1])
    surface.blit(bg1Hills[0], bg1Hills[1])

    mapController(False)
    player = playerController(False)

    display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the background Surface has the same format as the display Surface. Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) (or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)) to create a Surface that has the same pixel format. This improves performance when the background is, when the background is `blit` on  the display, because the formats are compatible and `blit` does not need to perform an implicit transformation.

```py
bg_surf = image.load('assets/PNG/Backgrounds/set1_background.png').convert()
bg1Colour = bg1Colour = transform.scale(bg_surf, (1280, 1024))
```

Comment: It did give me the frames back however only the hills where blitted

Comment: @MottledKarma517 Sorry I cant see your applicaiiton. Is the background transparent? Did you try `convert_alpha()`

Answer (score 1):

Just try to not using lists or tuple try by assingnig them so that the terminal should not check the lists and just use the signed values

Comment: How mutch of a performance  boost would that five though?

Comment: Some time it is also depends on the writing of the code, bcoz i had faced it a time ago and i tried to change my format from list to containers........and it helped me out....